# Uncaught TypeError: L.control.measure is not a function

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to add a Leaflet control measure my map, but I get an error in the console of browser. The error is in console is:

`Uncaught TypeError: L.control.measure is not a function`

I copied the folder of plugin to my public html, and added the url to css and js file of plugin in my index.html
`L.control.measure().addTo(map);`

and this is my index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./lib/leaflet-measure.css">
    <title>WEB GIS</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "map"></div>
    <button onclick= fullScreenView()>Full Screen</button>
    <div class="coordinate"></div>
    <button onclick="window.print()" >Print Map</button>
    
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/leaflet.browser.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/leaflet-measure.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure plugin code is loading? Have you had a look in the network section of the browser debugger?

Comment: @TomazicM thank you for you comment,yes the code is loading and i already check the network section;

Comment: Then it should work. Please edit your question and add relevant part of the code where you are using measure control.

Comment: thanks @TomazicM i reload the plugin and it works i just recheck the network section of the browser debugger idk now why but seems fine